# .htaccess and rewrite rule 404 not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new on `.htaccess` and `rewrite rules`.
So if my question is not relevant, please forgive me.

I have below htaccess code.

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]`

If i visit url like `www.example.com/category/0` it works.
But if i strip page url and last slash `www.exapmle.com/category` i see an ugly 404 page.

What is wrong with my htaccess directive?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Compeletely `.htaccess`**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^haber/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ article.php?link=$1&i=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct behaviour.
Actually, in a regular expression, a `+` means `at least one`.

When you use `([^/]+)` it means `at least one character which is not a slash`.
Your rule `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` means `at least one character which is not a slash` **/** `at least one character which is not a slash` **optional slash**.

That's why it does not work with only the first part url.
If you also want to handle `example.com/category` you'll need another rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L]
```